# NullPointerException Sometimes

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, try-catch

I have a function in my application and when user clicks button, it will display the nearest office. Functionality works in part of Sweden but does not work in the north of Sweden. I use try-catch statement and I'll catch the null pointer exception. When I shut down my network and the location, I get the error message, but in north Sweden, there is no message, the app just crashes. My code is down there. onFindOfficeClick () is a single function and independent. How can I solve this problem? I tried debug but fails to hit the error ... do not know what to do. I take all coordinates from xml file. Does anybaody have any suggestions?

```
private void onFindOfficeClick() {
    try {
        LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Service.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        List<String> providersName = lm.getProviders(false);
        if(providersName.size()>0){
            Location location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(providersName.get(0));
            float results [] = new float [1];
            final double longitude = location.getLongitude();
            final double latitude = location.getLatitude();
            final int officeCount = mOfficesInfo.length;
            double minDistance = 0;
            int officeNum = 0;
            for(int i=0; i<officeCount; i++){
                Location.distanceBetween(latitude, longitude,
                        mOfficesInfo[i].getLatitude(), mOfficesInfo[i].getLongitude(), results);
                if(i==0){
                    minDistance = results[0];
                } else if(results[0]<minDistance){
                    minDistance=results[0];
                    officeNum = i;
                }
            }
            int countryPosition = mCountries.indexOf(mOfficesInfo[officeNum].getCountry());
            mCountrySpiner.setSelection(countryPosition);
            mFindedOfficeName = mOfficesInfo[officeNum].getOfficeName();
            mOfficesSpiner.setSelection(officeNum);
        }
    }
    catch (NullPointerException e)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"check your network and GP:s connections",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add the exception stack trace to your question?

Comment: getLastKnownLocation may return null. You should definitely check for that condition, and also iterate through all location providers. Especially since you're also asking for providers that are disabled.

Answer (score 0):

put a null check before calling

```
LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Service.LOCATION_SERVICE);

if(lm!=null){
   lm.getProviders(false);.
 }
```

and also might be

```
        Location location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(providersName.get(0));
```

giving you null in the location variable so just do modify your code and put null check before getting latitude and laongitude from location.

```
 if(location!=null){

      final double longitude = location.getLongitude();
      final double latitude = location.getLatitude();
 }
```

becuase it is not good practice to catch NullPointerException in you code.

Comment: I wrote about my code and now we are testing it. I will inform you of the outcome, thanks,